# Pinch and zoom for google charts on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

Here is my plunkr for a google chart in angularJS
http://plnkr.co/edit/fpUD3HrMATqAc3E4Uxdc?p=preview

How do I get this map to be pinch and zoomable on a mobile device?

Right now the 'explorer' option enables zooming on a desktop by scrolling the mouse wheel, but I want it to be zoomable on a mobile device.

```
 var options = {
                        'title': 'Results',
                        'width': 400,
                        'height': 300,
                        'legend': { position: 'right' },
                        'focusTarget': 'category',
                        'explorer': {}
                    };
```

Please also note that I have a meta tag that is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

is there any way just the div containing the chart directive can be scalable?

Comment: Did you find any work-around for this issue? I am facing a similar one on Google Charts.